# Travel to Bulgaria and Romania with Italian residence permit

Tags: visas, romania, bulgaria, italian-residents

I have looked it up and the resources all talk about schengen visa, travelling with eu national family member etc. so I would like to get a more assuring answer about my situation:

I am a non-EU national with an Italian residence permit. My father is an Italian citizen. I will be travelling to Sofia and Bucharest next month with my girlfriend who is a British citizen. Do I need to get a visa to enter these two cities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both Bulgaria and Romania accept residence permits issued by the EU member countries and Schengen visas.

Proofs:

- <strike>http://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html</strike>

  - 2022-08-06: [MFA :: Visa for Bulgaria](https://www.mfa.bg/en/services-travel/consular-services/travel-bulgaria/visa-bulgaria): Visa C (for a short stay for the purpose of transit or a planned stay) - [more information (PDF)](https://www.mfa.bg/upload/715/VISA_C_en.pdf):

    - lists (in the PDF) as exception to the visa requirement:

    > Schengen (single) visa, long-stay visa, **permit for stay issued by any of the Schengen area states**;
- https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040

> Holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national visas or **residence permits issued by Schengen Member States**

Comment: Thank you. going to book hotels for our trip right now :)

Comment: The Bulagarian page you links to seems to claim that only holders of Schengen _visas_ are exempt from visa requirements there, whereas _residence permits_ from Schengen countries are not mentioned (but residence permits from Romania, Cyprus and Croatia are).

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk: Then it's serving a different page to me than it does to you. For the page I see, the only two instances of the word "residence" are in "valid visas and residence permits issued by Romania, Cyprus and Croatia" and "valid visas and residence permits issued by Romania, Cyprus and Croation" [sic].

Comment: The page from **Romania** does mention residence permits from Schengen member states, but that is not the page  (or the country!) I'm talking about.